# How do I remove my network from the recovery partition before sale?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, recovery

I'm about to put my old MBP up for sale, so I re-installed from the recovery partition after wiping the drive. But when I rebooted from the recovery partition to double-check I'd deleted everything, it connected to my wifi network. I've got two questions:

1. How do I remove my network credentials from the recovery partition?
2. What other personal information is it storing without my knowledge, and how do I wipe it?

Comment: Does command+option+p+r during boot erase those settings?  That is how the PRAM is cleared.  You should cycle it until you hear the reboot chime at least two times to be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was indeed to reset the NVRAM by holding cmd-alt-p-r during boot. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of macOS, the installer will boot into the setup which copies the NVRAM Wi-Fi credentials to a preferences file. Then, even if you clear the NVRAM, on the next boot, the OS will copy the Wi-Fi credentials back to the NVRAM.

To get around this:

1. After installation, shut down by pressing Cmd-Q
2. Boot into recovery mode (hold Cmd-R during boot)
3. Open the Terminal from Utilities menu > Terminal
4. Remove the wi-fi preferences (assuming your volume is named `Macintosh HD`:

   ```
   cd '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/'
   # For 10.15 and earlier:
   rm com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
   # For 11.x (Big Sur) and later:
   rm com.apple.wifi.known-networks.plist
   ```
5. Clear the nvram variables:

   ```
   nvram -d current-network
   nvram -d preferred-networks
   nvram -d preferred-count
   ```
6. Reboot the computer into setup assistant. Now it will not know the network.